# How to implement Facebook signup with passport

Tags: oauth, callback, routes, facebook-login

I have implemented the **facebook login** with hardcoded data in the DB so far, and now I want to implement the **signup** as well. how can I implement that in the below scenario without needing to repeat a lot of code ?

Please help me. Do I need a new **route** with the same **URL** for signup as well?
And how will I do about the e.g **user.FBSignup** **controller** ? How to implement that with the FacebookTokenStrategy ?

```
 /**************** FACEBOOK LOGIN ***********************/

    passport.use(new FacebookTokenStrategy({
        clientID: '562353024149441', //FACEBOOK_APP_ID
        clientSecret: '8b3d5b9923bda272239d3304f1b923ce', //FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3443/auth/facebook/callback",
        profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email']
    }, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log(profile.photos[0].value)
        user.FBLogin(profile.id, function (err, user) {
            return done(err, user);
        });
    }));

    app.post('/auth/facebook/token', passport.authenticate('facebook-token', {
        session: false
    }), (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.user)
        let token;
        try {
            token = jwt.sign({
                user: req.user,
            }, "supersecret")
            res.header('token', token)
        } catch (e) {
            return res.json({
                status: "error"
            })
            log('e', 'app.get(/auth/facebook/token - e - 230 : ' + e)
        }
        return res.send(req.user)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you want server-side login using https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook,or token approach using https://github.com/drudge/passport-facebook-token, base on your code, I recommend to watch this youtube videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zx6jnaLuB9Q&list=PLSpJkDDmpFZ7GowbJE-mvX09zY9zfYatI.